# Tool to make a goal meter with a custom fill image

Tags: javascript, donation

I'm searching for a good JavaScript tool to make a goal meter that fills with a custom image.

The only thing I've found so far was a plugin for WordPress called Donate Goal which hasn't been updated in over 2 years.

It can be a WP plugin, standalone JavaScript, or a straight PHP solution.

Comment: WordPress is PHP based so I'm thinking you'd also be fine with a PHP based solution that isn't specifically designed for WordPress yes?

Comment: Yeah i'm ok with PHP if you have any suggestion.